# smart contract transactions not committing to blockchain through nodejs web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

when i call any functionality of smart contract it returns me what its suppose to but doesnt reflect anyy changes when i query it. Its like the transaction never took place itself although it gave the right result from smart contract.Im using test-rpc. Have tested contract in truffle. and solidity browser. This is the simplified version of code that I've made.

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

console.log("Talking with a geth server", web3.version.api);

function test(){

var sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('contracts/digitalToken.sol','utf8')

var compiled = solc.compile(sourceCode);

console.log(compiled.contracts[":digitalToken"]);

var abiArray = compiled.contracts[":digitalToken"].interface;

abiArray = JSON.parse(abiArray);

var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);

var address = "0x1f81b5fa31d049b70556628cc01f22d362c41084";

var contractInstance = MyContract.at(address);

console.log(contractInstance);

var value=executeAddvid(contractInstance)

  console.log({message: "Success",value:value});

  console.log('after passing--');

  console.log({message: "Success",value:value});
var value1=readVidByUser(contractInstance);

console.log({message: "Success",value:value1});

  console.log('after passing--');

  console.log({message: "Success",value:value1});
}

function executeAddvid(contractInstance){

record = contractInstance;

return record.addVid.call('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000124',5,"ronaldo","0xc9f5a0572d95d5dea1331edcc192dacef51ecbb7",1000000000000000000);

}

function readVidByUser(contractInstance){

record = contractInstance;

return record.readVidByUser.call('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000124','0x1f81b5fa31d049b70556628cc01f22d362c41084');

}

test();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.call`, as in `record.addVid.call(...)`, you are not sending a transaction, but executing the call locally. For state-changing functions you want to use `.transact`, as in

```
record.addVid.call('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000124',5,"ronaldo","0xc9f5a0572d95d5dea1331edcc192dacef51ecbb7",1000000000000000000, {from:eth.coinbase})
```

Comment: The problem was the call function only, didnt realise it should be used for constant functions only. Thanks.